# Filtering table with dropdown menu - extra unwanted code displayed on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Overflowers,

I was trying to build a table which would be filtered by dropdown menu selection. The whole proccess works in this way:

**Index.html.erb**

```
render "selection"
```

This partial gives us a dropdown menu with selections.

**_selection.html.erb**

```
  <%= select_tag :area_selection,
                options_from_collection_for_select(Maps.all, :id, :location),
                :remote => 'true',
                :onchange => 'location_request(this.value);' %>
```

Selection from dropdown menu is being sent to a JS (which is located on index.html.erb)

**location_request javascript**

```
  function location_request(area_selection){
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/location_filter",
    type: "GET",
    data: { "requested_area" : area_selection },
    dataType: "script",
    success: function(data){
      // You are the winner :)
    },
    error: function(data){
      console.log(data);
    }
  })
}
```

From here, a variable is being sent to a controller

**controller**

```
def location_filter
    @filtered_locations = Post.where("location" => params[:requested_area])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
   end
```

In this stage, the location filter method returns a new "table" with filtered elements to a location_filter.js.erb

**location_filter.js.erb**

`$('#info').html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'filtered_table')%>");`

Here, a table is being imported to a #info div on a website via table partial

**_filtered_table.html.erb**

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">

    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <%= @filtered_locations.each do |filtered| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= filtered.location %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>

</table>
```

And this is the final format of the table which works perfectly fine as for a beginner.
The issue I face is that I get an extra table in text format which is being added on the same #info div

So it's the main issue - there is unwanted data displayed on the page in yellow. It needs to be removed somehow.

[image]

Question:
As far as I understand, the extra outcome is being made in controller (?) and then added to a front view.
What causes this duplicate of a table and how to avoid having it? :) Lame questionz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a controller error, is a error at your view. You're using `<%= %>` for your loop, and the `<%=` is used when you want to print something in your view, which, in your case, is the collection of objects that came from your controller. Try this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Location</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @filtered_locations.each do |filtered| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= filtered.location %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I removed the equal sign from your loop.

Comment: Worked well! It was just equal character which I need to delete. Didn't notice this.